# Android - Track Notification onclicked

Tags: android, notifications

I want to start a activity when users clicked on notification but there are no onclicked event for notification (?), so how can we know when the notification is clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Look into PendingIntent setup there.

The PendingIntent will get called when you click the notification.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

`notificationIntent` will be called when notification is clicked.